# Make background image to fit in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

I have used flexbox to create a grid which allows 3 images be aligned side by side. I have given them a width of 33.333% so they fit exactly.

However now I want to introduce a css hover effect where another image fades in when you hover over an image.

I have the effect working fine, however the issue I am having is that the image which fades in on hover is too big and as a result only about 75% of it appears in the container.

I got the code for the fade effect [here](http://www.gadgetronicx.com/image-cross-fade-on-hover-css-html), but although I have been manipulating the code I can't get the image to fit exactly 100% in the container. Both images are the exact same dimensions.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 1
}

.bord {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.crossfd {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0");
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}

.crossfd img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.crossfd img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box bord crossfd">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" width="100%" alt="Lou" />
  </div>
  <div class="box bord crossfd">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2" width="100%" alt="Lou" />
  </div>
  <div class="box bord crossfd">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3" width="100%" alt="Lou" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `background-size: cover;` on `.crossfd` class.

You may also try `contain` or `100%`, read the spec on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

> The `background-size` CSS property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.